# how to make a numeric data type with scale and precision in creating a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
create_table :offers do |t|
  t.numeric(15,2) :total_sales
  t.numeric(10,2) :price
  t.numeric(10,2) :discount
end
```

I am getting this error

```
create_offers.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
      t.numeric(15,2) :total_sales
                       ^
/home/gvpmahesh/code/present-app/present/db/migrate/20161017072207_create_offers.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
      t.numeric(10,2) :price
                       ^
/home/gvpmahesh/code/present-app/present/db/migrate/20161017072207_create_offers.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
      t.numeric(10,2) :discount
                       ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use decimal type to store financial data:

```
create_table :offers do |t|
  t.decimal :total_sales, precision: 15, scale: 2 
  t.decimal :price,       precision: 10, scale: 2 
  t.decimal :discount,    precision: 10, scale: 2 
end
```

Check out [official guides on migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
create_table :offers do |t|
  t.decimal :total_sales, precision: 15, scale: 2 
  t.decimal :price, precision: 10, scale: 2 
  t.decimal :discount, precision: 10, scale: 2 
end
```